# Looking for an algorithm which does Max Sum Clustering

Tags: clustering

I have a very limited background in data science and dataset processing and I was hoping I could get some help here. I am doing some work that requires clustering certain data points having $(x, y)$ position values and associated weight $W_i$ for each point.

I started with looking at k-means clustering since I know how many bins or k clusters the data needs to be divided into but I also have an additional criteria regarding the sum of weights $W_i$ in each cluster being less than/equal to a value $W_{max}$.

I need to essentially cluster the points along k different $y=C_i$ lines on XY plane such that the sum of weights for points along each line is less than/equal to $W_{max}$. Are there any constrained clustering algorithms that do this. It would a massive help if someone could point me to any open source C++ data science libraries that can help me achieve this.

Comment: This is more of an optimization problem than a clustering problem. Under the hood, kmeans is just moving points towards the nearest center, then recalculating the clusters after points have moved. Instead, treat this as a capacitated vehicle-type problem, where each Wmax is the "size of the truck" - figure out how to allocate your points effectively as if they were locations on a route. Alternatively, run a standard K-means algorithm, then figure out how to shift points to between clusters. Google has an optimzation library: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp

Answer (score 0):

Modify existing algorithms as necessary.

Tutorial example: https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means

This should also work if the desired clusters don't have the same weight sum as far as I can tell.